# How to display assn image randomly on a web browser using dom concept?

Tags: javascript, dom, javascript-objects

First by creating an image object using create element how do i set its attribute for top and left part of it in a function such that it displays the image at a random position in web??
My code doesn't displays random image..

Answer (score 0):

`Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1)` will give random number between 1 and 10.

Using .createElement() and absolute position:

```
var img = document.createElement('myImage');
myImage.src = 'pic.jpg';
myImage.style.top = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1) + 'px';
myImage.style.left = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1) + 'px';
```

Using Image Element constructor and margin:

```
var myImage = new Image();
myImage.src = 'pic.jpg';
myImage.style.marginTop = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1) + 'px';
myImage.style.marginLeft = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1) + 'px';
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style

Comment: <script>
function myFunction() {
for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
{ 
   var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = 'smile.png';
    img.style.top =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 400) + 1)+'px';
   img.style.left =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 400) + 1)+'px';
    document.getElementById("leftside").appendChild(img);
}
}
</script>
<div id="leftside"></div>
<div id="rightside"></div>.....it doesn't work....images generated serially not randomly @Vinny Mannello

Comment: @ManavJain you would need to use the marginTop and marginLeft with the code you mentioned. https://jsfiddle.net/sgrcm0z3/

Comment: Your code is missing a `}` at the end of the function. Also for fiddle, you will need to give it a link to the image, since smile.png does not live on their server. Lastly you need to look up some basic CSS styling to build your framework to handle this. Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qtnLax6m/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
function createImage(){   
 var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = 'yourImage.png';
    img.style.top = '10px';
    img.style.left = '10px';
    document.body.appendChild(img)
}
```

Instead of 10 you can set it now to a random number.